# Runtime exception when creating Bundle in JUnit test

Tags: java, android, junit

I'm testing some Java code that uses an android Bundle, and am getting a runtime exception whenever I create a Bundle in the unit test. The error I'm getting is java.lang.runtimeException at android.os.Bundle when I create the Bundle. It is running with the android SDK in the run configuration.
Has anyone run into this problem before?
Thanks!

Comment: some code and error strack trace?